"You are in emergency mode"
I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64bit.
It stopped booting normally al of a sudden.
First I tried to boot from the GRUB menu, using Linux 6.5.0-26-generic (recovery mode), but I got this error:

Kernel panic - not syncing: no working init found. Try passing init = option to kernel

Then I tried booting with Linux 6.5.0-25-generic (recovery mode), but I got the following error:

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type :"journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance (or press control-D to continue):

I pressed Control-D and I got this:

Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emerency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction)


What video hardware do you have (maybe an old Nvidia card?)? What driver are you using? Some of the old cards' driver modules don't compile with the gcc-12 needed for kernel 6.5

I have Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
.Driver version is 27.20.100.9664
This was running fine for a while. So could something have happened to the driver?
.By the way, I am running this on virtualbox

Update on this.
I was able to fix it by doing this:
I pressed Enter to go to maintenance, then used these commands:
update-initramfs -u -k all
update-grub
reboot

